# Host name mapping with virtual servers in GlassFish 3.1.2

Tags: glassfish, web-hosting, virtual-hosts, hostheaders

I have a GlassFish 3.1.2 server running 3 virtual hosts (virtual servers). 3 Default web applications are assigned to each servers.

Now if I type a url www.test-app1.com it should go to virtual server 1 and for www.test-app2.com it should go to virtual server 2 and so on.

So how should I configure the hostnames to corresponding virtual servers. Please help me getting it done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you created separate listeners for the virtual servers. if so, please create an A record in your DNS for www pointing to the corresponding IP that you have configured in the listener. assuming you have configured the listeners to listen to port 80 with seperate ips for the listeners. otherwise you will have include the port number in the url too.